# jquery - steal class from another element without hasClass()

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-mobile

I have a list

```
<ul class="thisList">
  <li><a href="" class="iconViewport icon_import"><span>Import</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="iconViewport icon_products"><span>Artikel</span></a></</li>
</ul>
```

I want to jquery-"steal" the 2nd class of each li, insert an img element and attach the stolen class to it. I cannot use hasClass since the class differs every time.

Can someone help me correct the following:

```
var thief = $('.thisList li a').className.split(/\s+/);
var booty = thief[1];
$('.thisList li a').after('<img class="someOtherClass'+booty+'" />');
```

I'm trying to put all classes of a into an array, then steal the 2nd element of this array and attach it to the inserted img tag.

Not working yet...  Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('.thisList li a')` yields a collection, not a single element so you need to iterate over it. You're also missing a space when building you images.

```
$('.thisList li a').each(function() {
    var thief = this.className.split(/\s+/);
    var booty = thief[1];
    $(this).after('<img class="someOtherClass ' + booty + '" />');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop over the links, and process each of them individually. Otherwise you cannnot get the `className` property for each of them. `$('.thisList li a').className` won't work anyway, as `className` is a property of the DOM element and not of the jQuery object.

This should do it:

```
$('.thisList li a').each(function() {
    var booty = this.className.split(/\s+/)[1];
    $(this).after('<img class="someOtherClass '+booty+'" />');
});
```

If "stealing" the class means removing it, then you can also call:

```
$(this).removeClass(booty);
```

**Update:** [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/UK2AT/)

Comment: @Felix King:   I added "." to ".each". It gets the steals the correct class (just listened to 200 alerts....) and adds it to the new img element. Problem is, I'm seeing 200x the same image. Either CSS-related or could it be in jquery. Thanks so far!

Comment: @Rocket: Nope. I want to "move" it from one item to another.

Comment: @frequent: Don't look at me, this isn't my answer, I just edited it.  Just add the `removeClass` line into the `each` to 'move' the class.

Comment: @frequent: Well if you "move" it from one element to the other, then you have to **add** it to one element and **remove** it from the original one. That was what I meant.

Comment: @frequent: I cannot tell you why you see the same image. The code above works. Are you setting the source of the image somewhere too?

Comment: Found it. var booty = thief[1]; did the trick. See next answer. How can I split the checkmark... checkmark to mu is too short, useful to Felix. THANKS!

Comment: @frequent: I don't get it. `var booty = this.className.split(/\s+/)[1];` is perfectly fine. It is just doing both things in one step... but anyway :)

Comment: @frequent: Well, you can see in my demo that it does work. Maybe you do some more stuff in your actual code...

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because $('.thisList li a') returns a jquery object, which has no property className.

Here's an untested attempt

```
$('.thisList li a'). each(function(index, el){
   var class2 = el.className.split(/\s+/)[1];
   $(el).after('<img class="someOtherClass '+class2+'" />');
})
```

Why on Earth is your variable named booty? And wow, 2 people beat me to it!

Comment: since the question was about "stealing", I tried to name the classes appropriately... stealing... thief... booty... :-)

Comment: And how is booty related to stealing? Do you steal other people's booties? Ahhhh, I see... like bootlegs... :)

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working:

```
var classString = '';

$('.thisList li a').each(function(){
  var elements = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
  classString += ' ' + elements[1];
});

$('.thisList').after($('<img class="someOtherClass'+classString+'"/>'));
```

Comment: This will only insert one image after the list, not after every link.